# Ideas about key management and android ios library for signing documents

Tags: android, ios, couchbase, gnupg, pgp

We are creating an app to share content in an offline/online scenario. We are planning to use Couchbase with some library that may sign data. We want people to be able to use our app even without going to the Internet and if possible they can use it also online. We need our app be able to sign every content that people create.

I need your help suggesting how to store keys in the app and on the server, and if there is something already made in this way.

Also, we need help finding a library that may sign all data to be stored in Couchbase lite in Android and iOS. I found openkeychain, but it doesn't seem that I can take from there only the library that is needed to sign the content.

We will really appreciate your suggestions.

Have a big hug,

Carlos.

Answer (score 0):

I once made an app that worked something like that (with the signing and offline/online part). So I will give you my two cents.

For the signing I used a drawing library, simple as that and just when the drawing is ended save it in an output file. (Just keep in mind to store the path somewhere and after the picture is sent, delete the picture so it won't take too much of users device space).

For the offline/online part you should see [evernote job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) as it's a great library for sending data to API. The job is then created and tried to be send (it usually send some json request), and if the user is offline it goes in the RESCHEDULE part and it is rescheduled for as long as you want and then when the user goes online the job (with it's data) will be sent to API. And it's working great with RxJava and retrofit which is a big plus (at least for me).

For the storing part look up for [hawk's store](https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk) as it is a great key-value store library, very easy to use and works very well to. Just try reading the page, everything is described straight forward.

All this is for the android part, as for the iOS you'll have to find another one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the question is about a digital signing, not hand-signing. You can use PGP (as you suggested with the tags). For the Android, there is [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) and for iOS, you can use [ObjectivePGP](http://objectivepgp.com) framework. That will cover the signing part.

One approach would be to generate keys on devices and send public key to the server, then use that key to sign data on device and verify on the server (with public key).